# Error: CSS: unicode-range: Too many values or values are not recognized

Tags: css, google-font-api, unicode-range

Im doing a case study using validator.w3 and its showing me 3 different errors to with unicode-range and i can't seem to figure out whats the explanation behind it online. At the unicode range U+A8E0-A8FB,U+A720-A7FF and U+FFFD
Anyone knows about this issue please let me know much appreciated!

[image]

```
            @font-face {
            font-display: block;
            font-family: 'Raleway';
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 700;
            src: local('Raleway Bold Italic'), local('Raleway-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v14/1Ptpg8zYS_SKggPNyCgw9qR_DNCb71ka4ZiO.woff2) format('woff2');
            unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
            }
            @font-face {
            font-display: block;
            font-family: 'Raleway';
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 700;
            src: local('Raleway Bold Italic'), local('Raleway-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v14/1Ptpg8zYS_SKggPNyCgw9qR_AtCb71ka4Q.woff2) format('woff2');
            unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;↩
            }
            @font-face {
            font-display: block;
            font-family: 'Poppins';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 700;
            src: local('Poppins Bold'), local('Poppins-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v9/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7Z11lFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');
            unicode-range: U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;
```

Comment: Try removing all `↩` characters from your code (`↩` is _Leftwards Arrow With Hook_ `U+21A9`).

Comment: Hi my bad that was a snippet took from the validator actual code does not have the arrow

Comment: This CSS validator defect has now been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to be doing the same case as well. From what I've gathered, U+A720-A7FF can be found in Poppins font, just not in the stated font face. That's the reason why there's an error. I hope this helps you.[U+A720-A7FF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7i0o.png)

Comment: That explains it! Thanks! May i ask how did you found out that, that was the case?

Comment: the correct solution is indeed this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69697367/1243247