# W3C CSS validator is giving errors on @font-face unicode-range

Tags: html, css, font-face, unicode-range

Since few days ago W3C CSS validator started to be more strict and started to give errors on this type of CSS3 implementation (this type of CSS3 files are everywhere and they were used for example by Google Fonts):

```css
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), url("fonts/XRXV3I6Li01BKofIOuaBXso.woff2") format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
  font-display: fallback;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), url("fonts/XRXV3I6Li01BKofIO-aBXso.woff2") format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
  font-display: fallback;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), url("fonts/XRXV3I6Li01BKofINeaB.woff2") format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  font-display: fallback;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Nunito Bold'), local('Nunito-Bold'), url("fonts/XRXW3I6Li01BKofAjsOUbuvISTs.woff2") format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
  font-display: fallback;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Nunito Bold'), local('Nunito-Bold'), url("fonts/XRXW3I6Li01BKofAjsOUb-vISTs.woff2") format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
  font-display: fallback;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Nunito Bold'), local('Nunito-Bold'), url("fonts/XRXW3I6Li01BKofAjsOUYevI.woff2") format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  font-display: fallback;
}
```

With the following error on `unicode-range`: `Too many values or values are not recognized`

Apparently many developers have used unicode ranges with multiple values and multiples ranges for their fonts because [MDN says it is OK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range), but apparently it is not, since according to W3C docs, the [syntax](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/unicode-range.html) for `unicode-range` is:

```
unicode-range: single codepoint | codepoint range | wildcard range | initial | inherit;
```

That is, apparently many ranges are not possible.

**How to tackle this issue?**

This seems to be a very strict approach of W3C since many browsers support several ranges, and it indeed saves bandwidth because allows more flexibility on which font files are to be downloaded.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69585993/error-css-unicode-range-too-many-values-or-values-are-not-recognized-but

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: CSS: unicode-range: Too many values or values are not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69516381/error-css-unicode-range-too-many-values-or-values-are-not-recognized)

Comment: @Luuk no, they just make a workaround, please read my question carefully, thanks

Comment: Multiple ranges are definitely valid. The latest W3C recommendation standard gives examples of such in [4.6. Using character ranges to define composite fonts](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#composite-fonts)  as does the latest [Editor's draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#example-3fd9c28a). I conclude that this is just a bug in the validator.

Comment: The spec also says of the [unicode-range property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#unicode-range-desc) "This descriptor defines the set of Unicode codepoints that may be supported by the font face for which it is declared. The descriptor value is a comma-delimited list of Unicode range (<urange>) values."

Comment: @Alohci, interesting, but W3C CSS validator is giving error on multiple ranges, try yourself: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: I did try. The validator even fails the examples in the spec. Ergo, it's a validator bug. It happens.

Comment: @Alohci do you know how do I report that to W3C? My whole test suite is failing because we are obliged to use the W3C validation. And BTW, can you make a reply here, such that I set it as the correct answer? Thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues. I'll write up a full answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a defect of the validator.

The CSS Fonts Specification defines [the `unicode-range` property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#unicode-range-desc) as

```
Value: <urange>#
```

where `<urange>` can be any of

> ```
> single codepoint (e.g. U+416)<br>
>     a Unicode codepoint, represented as one to six hexadecimal digits
>
> interval range (e.g. U+400-4ff)<br>
>     represented as two hyphen-separated Unicode codepoints indicating the 
>      inclusive start and end codepoints of a range
>
> wildcard range (e.g. U+4??)<br>
>     defined by the set of codepoints implied when trailing '?' characters 
>     signify any hexadecimal digit
> ```

And [the # means](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#mult-comma)

> ... that the preceding type, word, or group occurs one or more times, separated by comma tokens (which may optionally be surrounded by white space and/or comments).

The specification underlines this formal definition in prose:

> This descriptor defines the set of Unicode codepoints that may be supported by the font face for which it is declared. The descriptor value is a comma-delimited list of Unicode range () values.

It also provides examples. [Example 30](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#example-3fd9c28a) is particular useful:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: STIXGeneral;
  src: local(STIXGeneral), url(/stixfonts/STIXGeneral.otf);
  unicode-range: U+000-49F, U+2000-27FF, U+2900-2BFF, U+1D400-1D7FF;
}
```

If you submit this to the CSS validator, it will report the same error. Since the spec is authoritative, the validator must be in error.

Comment: I submitted the bug towards W3C, they will fix it, thanks https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/350

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: This answer is no longer valid because there was a bug on in the validator**, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69711789/724039

The correct solution <strike>is</strike> was to follow the 'docs' at [MDN Webdocs: unicode-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range)

change: `unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;`

to:

```
unicode-range: U+0102-0103;
unicode-range: U+0110-0111;
unicode-range: U+1EA0-1EF9;
unicode-range: U+20AB;
```

Comment: you are GREAT! I read that docs, but I though they were alternatives and that you could not have several `unicode-range`

Comment: doesn't seem to work, at least on Chrome

Comment: this doesnt work, it only applies the last unicode-range definition

Comment: I added info about the defect on the validator which is fixed. (and is the accepted answer to this question)